# Moonlandsoft/yii2-phpexcel - encoding views

Tags: yii2

I have a problem with Yii export library. I just follow the documentation in this link: https://github.com/moonlandsoft/yii2-phpexcel , output have come out like encoding views.
[image]
my code view:

```
\moonland\phpexcel\Excel::export([
    'isMultipleSheet' => true,
    'models' => [
        'sheet1' => Order::find()->all(),     
    ], 'columns' => [
        'sheet1' => ['id','phone','total'],   
    ],
    'headers' => [
        'sheet1' => ['column1' => 'id','column2' => 'phone', 'column3' => 'total']       
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got the xlsx file source directly embeded into your web page, because you didn't send proper headers. Your view template is fine but your controller action should look like this:

```
public function actionExport()
{
    //set headers to prevent caching
    $headers = \Yii::$app->response->headers;
    $headers->set('Expires', 'Mon, 1 Apr 1974 05:00:00 GMT');
    $headers->set('Last-Modified', gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
    $headers->set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate');
    $headers->set('Pragma', 'no-cache');

    //use renderPartial instead of render because we don't want to add layout
    $content = $this->renderPartial('export');
    //send content as attachment with filename my-export.xlsx and proper mime type
    return \Yii::$app->response->sendContentAsFile(
            $content,
            'my-export.xlsx',
            ['mimeType' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet']
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how to set the default sheet to open the first sheet? When I open an excel file, a sheet opens: worksheet.